# Android Studio Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dsl

So I get this error on my android studio project after opening up the work I did in school at home by using GitHub:

Error:(19, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
Possible causes:

The project 'LoginScreen' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

Here are what my settings are:

In my project structure I have my Compile SDK version set to API 19 and my Build tools version set to 19.1.0

[image: My project gradle]

[image: My app.build.gradle]

PS: Would upgrading my build tools to the latest one allow me to continue using the API 19?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the bottom six lines from your project's `build.gradle` file (`android` and top-level `dependencies` closure), as they do not belong there.

In the future, please post the **text** of your Gradle build files, not screenshots.